# Exclude and Include records from data table

Tags: mysql

The following query will exclude all type_id that equals 4.

```
SELECT *
FROM `release` r
LEFT JOIN type t ON t.release_group_id = r.release_group_id AND t.type_id = 4
WHERE t.type_id IS NULL
```

But, i also want to include all type_id that equals 2.

How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add `OR` in your `WHERE` clause and add type id 2 in `ON` clause

```
SELECT *
FROM `release` r
LEFT JOIN type t ON t.release_group_id = r.release_group_id AND t.type_id IN(4,2)
WHERE t.type_id IS NULL OR t.type_id = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

The query doesn't look right, but you can include additional type id as follows:

```
LEFT JOIN type t ON t.release_group_id = r.release_group_id AND t.type_id in (4, 2)
```